# How to make real time trigger in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a small airline project and I have stuck in this problem.
The problem is that I want to update the field DABAY (status) in below table to 1 when our current time passed the time in field THOIGIANBAY (time will fly).
I have made a trigger below the table code but it had error syntax and it didn't work.
Thanks guys for helping!

```
CREATE TABLE chuyenbay ( 
    MACHUYENBAY varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    MAMAYBAY varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    SANBAYDI varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    SANBAYDEN varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    THOIGIANBAY datetime NOT NULL, --time will fly
    THOIGIANDEN datetime NOT NULL,
    TRANSITION varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL
    DABAY bit(1) DEFAULT '0'  --status
)

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER CHUYENBAY_VE_capnhat_TRANGTHAI
AFTER INSERT ON chuyenbay
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE thoigianbandau datetime;
    SELECT THOIGIANBAY INTO @thoigianbandau
    FROM chuyenbay
    WHERE chuyenbay.MACHUYENBAY = inserted.MACHUYENBAY
    IF (NOW() > @thoigianbandau)
        THEN 
            UPDATE chuyenbay SET chuyenbay.DABAY = 1;
            UPDATE ve SET ve.TRANGTHAI = 2;
    END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Triggers are not real time, they are event driven.

Comment: @Shadow So are there any ways to update a field like that?

Comment: I'm not sure I would. In any query you can compare the 2 fields when the query runs and take appropriate action. Such a query could be persisted in a view and your application can access the view instead of the table. Or you could use a generated column as well (depending on your MySQL version). It all depends on your business requirements.